# Как изменить иконку приложения и его имя после установки

Tags: c++, c++builder, apk, radstudio, project

Нужно изменить не имя проекта, не имя (apk) установочного файла, а когда файл уже установился и в меню телефона появляется иконка, ее и нужно изменить.

**P.S.**
Я нашел 3 манифеста  в проекте. в каком именно, и какую строку менять?

Comment: Я понял только, что, "когда огонь горит, она в бухте". И более - ничего.

Comment: @BuilderC, он хочет динамическую иконку андроид-приложения. Ставишь приложение, а оно само себе иконку меняет. Спрашивает, как это сделать.